# imdbpy rating data missing

Tags: python-2.7, imdb, imdbpy

i have a question about the [imdbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/index.html) module for python, for some reason i can't retrieve some data about tv shows even though they exist on the imdb.com website.
for example if i use this code:

```
from imdb import IMDb
i = IMDb()
s = i.search_movie('killjoys')
m = i.get_movie(s[0].movieID)
print m.get('rating')
```

the result is **None** even though on the [imdb.com](http://imdb.com) it's available
so what should i so here? and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i found is to use a different library called **omdb**

```
import omdb
tv_show_name = "hannibal"
movie = omdb.get(title=tv_show_name, fullplot=True, media_type="series")
rating = movie.imdb_rating
```

there you go this might help someone someday ;)

Comment: After looking at David Albernai's solution below, you just have to update the IMDb object to load all results. Also, omdb is not as well designed as IMDbPY IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Consider two things:

1. the Movie objects in the result list from a query contains only limited data (the ones you can see from a search on the web).
2. for a series, the "combined" page doesn't show the rating.

So, in your example, the first result would refer to imdbID 3952222.
You can update the (main) information using:

```
i.update(m)
```

but again this would only add main information, by default (the ones from the http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3952222/combined page)

So, you need to also parse the "vote details" page with:

```
i.update(m, ['main', 'vote details'])
```

(or just 'vote details' if you don't need to fetch and parse the main details).

Comment: thanks for the help dude but i gave up on this not just because of that also it doesn't handle non ascii characters correctly, i found a better library called omdb and it works like a charm ;)